# 1004 runtime when moving a custom chart from one chart sheet to another

Tags: vba, excel

I'm getting a 1004 runtime (The specified dimension is not valid for the current chart type) when trying to create and move a new chart to a pre-existing chart sheet. I have no clue with this one. Where am I going wrong? When I step through the program with the debugger it completely works.

```
Sub CreateChart(chartName As String, chartLocation As String, freqRng As Range, binRng As Range, meanRng As Range, meanHgt As Range)
Dim chrt As Chart
Set chrt = ThisWorkbook.Charts.Add
chrt.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
chrt.SetSourceData freqRng, xlColumns
chrt.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = binRng

With chrt.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .Values = meanHgt
    .XValues = meanRng
    .ChartType = XlChartType.xlXYScatterLines
End With

chrt.HasAxis(xlCategory, xlSecondary) = False
chrt.HasAxis(xlValue, xlSecondary) = False
chrt.Location xlLocationAsObject, chartLocation
End Sub
```

chartName is unused ATM. This is technically a column chart with one series that's an XY scatter/lines so that I can make a mean line.

Thanks for any input!

Comment: When you run into the error and go into debug, what line is your error on?

Comment: @TMH8885 It's on 'chrt.Location xlLocationAsObject, chartLocation' and only happens when the chart is actually moved from the one sheet to the other. Is there a way to move the chart without .Location and then have it not take up the whole chartsheet and be unsizeable?

Answer (score 0):

I "solved" this problem. The code was working when stepping and the error didn't affect anything at all, so I just added On Error Resume Next so that it would just skip. Be careful, that can cause you to miss fatal errors. However, if you really know nothing is going wrong, just use it.